# How can I share Array from one Controller to another

Tags: scala, twitter, reddit

I'm new to scala. What am I doing is trying to make twitter bot that collects posts from Reddit and post them to Twitter. I have to Controllers and I need to pass an array with marked reddit posts, that user want to tweet, From one controller to another. I've tried to use Singleton and Cache but, i don't know why, it's not working for me

RedditController:

```
var pickedToTwitter : List[RedditJsonData] = _
  def pickedRedditsPost = Action { implicit  request =>

    redditsForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithError => {
        formWithError.errors.foreach(er => Logger.debug(er.message))
        Ok(views.html.main("asd")(Html("error")))
      },
      goodOne => {
        sessionCache.set("1",pickedToTwitter = redditsJson.filter(el => goodOne.redditsList(redditsJson.indexOf(el)).checked))

        //Ok(views.html.main("asd")(Html(pickedToTwitter.mkString)))
        Redirect("/redditsSend")
      }
    )
  }
```

TwitterController

```
  val tweet : Option[List[RedditJsonData]] = sessionCache.get[List[RedditJsonData]]("1")


    def send = Action.async { request =>
      //for(i <- 0 to tweet.toList.length)  {
      val data = Map(
        "status" -> "asf"
      )

      var rt: RequestToken = new RequestToken(request.session.get("token").get, request.session.get("secret").get)

      ws.url("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=" + tweet.get(0).url).sign(OAuthCalculator(KEY, rt)).post("ignored").map(response => {
        Ok(views.html.main("asd")(Html(response.body)))
        //Redirect(response.body)
      })
    //}
  }
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. Controller A gets a request. It then produces some Array and then you want to cache it so that another later request coming to ControllerB can access it?

Comment: how did you aquire the sessionCache? Injected?

Comment: @mfirry Yes, I have Array of reddits and I want to give that array to other controller so I can tweet that reddits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example you see a Singleton and a Cache. You need to be careful with the imports if they are slightly wrong everything crashes. I didn't get the CacheAPI to work the error needs more attention as it seems.

The singleton:

```
package controllers.singletons
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class Test() {
  val message:String = "Test"
}
```

Controller Application:

```
package controllers
import javax.inject.Inject
import controllers.singletons.Test
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.cache._
import play.api.mvc._

class Application @Inject()(test:Test)extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    Cache.set("a", "this is a test")
    Ok(views.html.index(test.message))
  }
}
```

Controller CacheTest:

```
package controllers
import play.api.cache.Cache
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

class CacheTest  extends Controller{
  def cache = Action {

    Ok(views.html.cacheWorks(Cache.get("a").getOrElse("Not Working").asInstanceOf[String]))
  }
}
```

I have two routes

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET     /cache                      controllers.CacheTest.cache
```

And there are two HTML pages which are getting the cache and singleton content and display it. I think that is what you can see from the code, which is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thank you, helped me with Singleton a lot.

Comment: you can also inject as an member, but this seems not to work that well if you want to have it "val" and not "var". Hold in mind that it's not really concurrency save. It would be better to use an Actor. If you want I can provide an Example.

Comment: If you can give an example, that would be great!

Comment: I tried to, but it didnt work well and I am using a "sandbox project" for those things, and think that some reference are faulty, sorry. But it's really simple. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka#Dependency-injecting-actors
(1) create an actor with default constructor (2) create a module (see my link) (3) inject it named. I have a big project with many sources where it's working. Iam using 3 separate ActorSystems and inject them where I want them. But it's to big to build an example, that is working. If problem occur ask me in the chat.